# How can activity be garbage collected when orientation rotation occurs?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

If views hold an Activity context and an orientation rotation occurs, then the existing activity will be destroyed. However, since the views that existed has a reference to the previous activity the previous activity will not be garbage collected.

How can this dilemma be solved?